# Illustrator (.ai) to Photoshop (.psd) conversion

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, file-conversion

I happen to have an Illustrator file which I want to convert to a psd. However my Problem is, that even though I have separate layers in Illustrator

[image]

it wont let me choose to "write layers"

[image]

so what am I doing wrong? I kinda feel dumb, since [others](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27550/is-there-a-way-to-convert-from-illustrator-to-photoshop-and-maintain-things-like) seem to have no problem with all that.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in PS that you cant already do in AI?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft our unity dev told me that unity can read psd files directly giving him more control over which layers he does want to display, etc. This is why he has requested for the files to be in .psd format.

Comment: ooh ok, fair enough then!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probably because your export color profile (RGB) does not match your document color profile (CMYK).

Change "color model" to CMYK